# Loading MySQL table into a text file?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

It has been answered that how to load data from text file into SQL databases.

However, I did not find any question regarding how to load table into text file.

I am using JDBC and MySQL on my own PC.

How can I load a table into a text file ?

The data should be neatly organized like a matrix in the text file, including column names.

**Best regards to the people reading this question.**

Comment: Use csv (Comma Separated Values)

Comment: `"It has been answered that how to load data from text file into SQL databases."` -- Who is asking you this?

Comment: `"The data should be neatly organized like a matrix in the text file, including column names."` -- Use `String.format(...)`, and experiment with your code a bit. Please feel free to come on back with your code if you're stuck with it.

Comment: http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jdbc/how-to-export-data-from-database-to-csv-file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to export it as a .txt?

IF so you can just do this

```
SELECT * FROM table
INTO OUTFILE '/.../filelocation.txt'
```

You have several options of delimiting, line feed, and such. Look at this [link](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/) for some examples.

Comment: Thanks, it has been run successfully, but where is the file ? I tried directly with /test.txt, where is this file ?

Comment: It can save into any directory you want. For example: INTO OUTFILE 'C:/whatever/../blah.txt @GeekCat

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table
INTO OUTFILE '/path/outfile.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it to csv. 
Try connecting to jdbc by connector. 
Then make a query to result set, knowing table structure. 
In query you should copy each row to variables - ints, Strings and for each row create string. While creating string, remember to add structure for data, like "," sign. 
Then you have for example table `Person ( id , name , surname )` 
so you exchange it during reading select query from database to string: `"1,'john','doe'`

You can concatenate String with `"+"` sign and you have to do it in a loop. Then add `"\r\n"` to each line to end line in text.